# Parent div ingnores height of child because of its float

Tags: html, css

The parent height is set to auto  but does not grow, because the child div has a float to the left. What is happening here, how can I fix it?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xksbs/2/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="content">....</div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap{
background: blue;
width:600px;
height: auto;
border: solid 3px;
}

.content{
background: red;
width:200px;
padding: 10px;
height: auto;
float: left;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either add `overflow:auto` to your `wrap div`

or `clear the floats.`

Solution 1:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="content">....</div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap{
    background: blue;
    width:600px;
    height: auto;
    border: solid 3px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

SOLUTION 2:

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="content">....</div>
   <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clr
{
clear:both;
}
```

Please refer the below link for better understanding:
[Clearing floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could change the overflow parameter but this impacts the overflow behaviour. Using floats goes together with a clear:all div, it's like tracing a imaginative line under your flatings to start over on a new line.. some kind of line break but for the floats...
Add a last sibling div with style clear:both

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="content">....</div>
   <div style="clear:both"></div>
 </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xksbs/6/

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:auto;` to the parent `<div>`: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7SgvL/)

Code:

```
.wrap{
    background: blue;
    width:600px;
    height: auto;
    border: solid 3px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong in setting float left to the child, You have to just add `overflow:hidden` to the parent div to achieve your need

http://jsfiddle.net/Xksbs/4/

Answer (score 1):

Just like Vincent Durpez said, and here you can see the

js fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/Xksbs/5/]